# Yet another Python looping over JSON array

Tags: python, json

I spent several hours on this, tried everything I found online, pulled some of the hair left on my head...
I have this JSON sent to a Flask webservice I'm writing :

```
{'jsonArray': '[
    {
        "nom":"0012345679",
        "Start":"2018-08-01",
        "Finish":"2018-08-17",
        "Statut":"Validee"
    },
    {
        "nom":"0012345679",
        "Start":"2018-09-01",
        "Finish":"2018-09-10",
        "Statut":"Demande envoyée au manager"
    },
    {
        "nom":"0012345681",
        "Start":"2018-04-01",
        "Finish":"2018-04-08",
        "Statut":"Validee"
    },
    {
        "nom":"0012345681",
        "Start":"2018-07-01",
        "Finish":"2018-07-15",
        "Statut":"Validee"
    }
    ]'}
```

I want to simply loop through the records :

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/graph', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_data = request.get_json()
        print(req_data) #-> shows JSON that seems to be right
        ##print(type(req_data['jsonArray']))
        #j1 = json.dumps(req_data['jsonArray'])
        #j2 = json.loads(req_data['jsonArray'])
        #data = json.loads(j1)
        #for rec in data:
        #    print(rec) #-> This seems to consider rec as one of the characters of the whole JSON string, and prints every character one by one
        #for key in data:
        #     value = data[key]
        #     print("The key and value are ({}) = ({})".format(key, value)) #-> TypeError: string indices must be integers


        for record in req_data['jsonArray']:
            for attribute, value in rec.items(): #-> Gives error 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
                print(attribute, value)
```

I believe I am lost between JSON object, python dict object, strings, but I don't know what I am missing. I really tried to put the JSON received through json.dumps and json.loads methods, but still nothing. What am I missing ??

I simply want to loop through each record to create another python object that I will feed to a charting library like this :

```
df = [dict(Task="0012345678", Start='2017-01-01', Finish='2017-02-02', Statut='Complete'),
      dict(Task="0012345678", Start='2017-02-15', Finish='2017-03-15', Statut='Incomplete'),
      dict(Task="0012345679", Start='2017-01-17', Finish='2017-02-17', Statut='Not Started'),
      dict(Task="0012345679", Start='2017-01-17', Finish='2017-02-17', Statut='Complete'),
      dict(Task="0012345680", Start='2017-03-10', Finish='2017-03-20', Statut='Not Started'),
      dict(Task="0012345680", Start='2017-04-01', Finish='2017-04-20', Statut='Not Started'),
      dict(Task="0012345680", Start='2017-05-18', Finish='2017-06-18', Statut='Not Started'),
      dict(Task="0012345681", Start='2017-01-14', Finish='2017-03-14', Statut='Complete')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing is wrapped in single quotes, meaning it's a string and you need to parse it.

```
for record in json.loads(req_data['jsonArray']):
```

Looking at your commented code, you did this:

```
j1 = json.dumps(req_data['jsonArray'])
data = json.loads(j1)
```

Using `json.dumps` on a string is the wrong idea, and moreover `json.loads(json.dumps(x))` is just the same as `x`, so that just got you back where you started, i.e. `data` was the same thing as `req_data['jsonArray']` (a string).

This was the right idea:

```
j2 = json.loads(req_data['jsonArray'])
```

but you never used `j2`.

As you've seen, iterating over a string gives you each character of the string.

Comment: Man... Thanks. I actually tried to use j2 with this : `for key in j2:    value = j2[key]` But I got the `list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

Comment: May I ask,  does that mean that I wasn't getting a proper JSON in the first place ? The whole thing shouldn't have been wrapped in single quotes ?

Comment: Yes, `j2` is a list of dicts, you can't treat it like a dict. And yes, `request.get_json()` should return a completely parsed data structure. `req_data['jsonArray']` should already be a list.